# Suma intercalada entre dos vectores

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con el siguiente ejercicio: debo hacer un código de tal forma que me sume dos arreglos del mismo tamaño, de forma intercalada y luego lo guarde en otro arreglo.
Ejemplo: Arreglo1 : 2 4 6 8
Arreglo2 : 4 6 8 10
resultado: 8 8 16 16

He hecho el siguiente código pero no me funciona, apreciaria si me pueden ayudar.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Calculo {
    Datos obj = new Datos();
    int resultado[];
    public void Suma(){
        obj.pedirTamas();
        obj.pedirNums();
        resultado = new int[obj.tama];
        int k=0,j=1;
        for(int i=0;i<resultado.length;i++){
            resultado[i] = obj.arreglo1[k]+obj.arreglo2[j];
            j--;
            k++;
        }
    }
    public void imprimirResult(){
        String mostrar="";
        for(int i=0;i<resultado.length;i++){
            mostrar += resultado[i]+" ";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,mostrar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que tener en cuenta el control del loop para este ejercicio, segun entiendo la logica de este ejercicio tiene que ser:

A1 = [2 4 6 8]
A2 = [4 6 8 10]

Por ende el algoritmo tiene que ser

Resultado = [( A1[0] + A2[1] ) , ( A1[1] + A2[0] )...] siguiendo esa logica cada iteracion del arreglo tiene que retornar 2 valores del arreglo resultado.

Por lo que el codigo deberia quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Calculo {
    Datos obj = new Datos();
    int resultado[];
    public void Suma(){
        obj.pedirTamas();
        obj.pedirNums();
        resultado = new int[obj.tama];
        for(int i = 0; i<resultado.length; i+=2){
            resultado[i] = obj.arreglo1[i]+obj.arreglo2[i+1];
            resultado[i+1] = obj.arreglo1[i+1]+obj.arreglo2[i]
        }
    }
    public void imprimirResult(){
        String mostrar="";
        for(int i=0;i<resultado.length;i++){
            mostrar += resultado[i]+" ";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,mostrar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Carlos, me funcionó, muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda :)